# Presto Singleton Class in qds-sdq-py needs to interact with different API Tokens at runtime

Tags: python-3.6, tornado, presto

Our application (python 3.6) is a query generator, allowing its users to query several tables from different DataBases.
We are trying to add Qubole support. Currently trying to assimilate a Presto engined clusters.
We have several API tokens and need to be able to query different presto DB’s simultaneously.
We started implementing this using qds_sdk, however, it seems that the class Qubole is a Singlton and the Class PrestoCommand interact with it directly.

Please consider qds-sdk-py/example/qubole_presto_api_example.py
https://github.com/qubole/qds-sdk-py/blob/master/example/qubole_presto_api_example.py

lines 67-68

```
  Qubole.configure(api_token=‘YOUR-QUBOLE-API-TOKEN’)
  get_results(execute_query(“select * from  default.cities limit 100;“))
```

Our service require the ability to have several Qubole.configure objects and to query them according to user interactions.
I.E:

```
    q1 =  Qubole.configure(api_token=‘Token1’)
    q2 =  Qubole.configure(api_token=‘Token2’)
    *user triggeres an event*
    q1.get_results(execute_query(“query”))
```

How would you proceed? Should I implement some lock before trying to access the table?

Comment: Hi Lolu, Could you elaborate why do you need multiple API tokens to query different Presto DBs?

Comment: @Ashish 
we have a query generator, part of the service need to use the presto in order to cach data and present it to the user so he will know what he wants to filter out/in,
other part of the process need to use presto in order to create the complex query the user asked for.

Comment: Are you using Qubole platform?

Comment: If Yes, I would recommend to create a production user which would be having access of all the required resources (DBs, tables etc.) and then user that user's token to run the queries.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to use different API Tokens to send queries to different Qubole accounts (and therefore Presto clusters), I believe you have that sorted with instantiating different Qubole clients.

If you need to wait for each query to complete before moving on, then you could also use a loop with polling. Here's a quick example of how you might approach it for one query:

```
presto_command=PrestoCommand.create(query=my_query, label='presto_cluster_label')
while True:
    sts = PrestoCommand.find(presto_command.id).status
    if sts == u'error' or sts == u'done' or sts == u'cancelled':
        break
    time.sleep(10)

if sts != u'done':
    error_str = presto_command.get_log()
    sys.stderr.write(error_str)
    raise QuboleError(error_str)

presto_command.get_results()
```

Comment: i dont have to use the token? i can handle that only with the labels?

Comment: You still use the tokens for each connection (or client).  However my example was to just show how to poll and wait for the query to be done. You’d need to do that for each connection/client. Maybe I haven’t understood your question completely. Could you rephrase it if I missed it?

Comment: i need several tokens to work and get queries on the same time and be thread safe.
currently i lean towards using the API directly with http requests, but was looking for a easier way